# Triggering a Dialogbox from a View

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity, scoring

I would like the Dialog Box to appear when the user's lives have hit 0. So any collision with an obstacle means the lives is decremented and becomes 0, which is when the game stops. That's okay, but how do I then 'break' out of the View, and into the Activity which started the View, to create a Dialog, which asks for the user to input a name, and takes the score from the View and then saves it to a file?

The saving to a file part I think I can work out, it's the breaking out of the View with the score int and creating the Dialog i'm confused about.

This is my GameActivity:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener 
{
FileStore fs;
GameView gv;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
boolean continueMusic = true;
private final int DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    continueMusic = true;
    fs = new FileStore();

    //full screen
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    int speed = i.getIntExtra("s", 0);

    gv = new GameView(this, speed);
    setContentView(gv);     

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);      //makes the audio controllable

    sensorManager=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensorManager.registerListener(this, sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        float x=event.values[0];

        if (x < 0)
        {
            gv.setSpriteState(2);
        }
        if (x > 0)
        {
            gv.setSpriteState(1);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}   

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    if(!continueMusic)
    {
        MusicManager.pause();
    }
}

public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    continueMusic = false;
    MusicManager.start(this,R.raw.europa);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.save, null);
        final EditText t = (EditText) textEntryView
                .findViewById(R.id.save_edit);
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.smalllogo)
                .setTitle(R.string.save2)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.save3,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                Player p= new Player(t.getText().toString(), gv.getScore());
                                ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();
                                if(players==null)
                                    players= new ArrayList<Player>();
                                players.add(p);
                                fs.saveScores(players);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.save4,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                            }
                        }).create();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

And this is the GameView (trimmed, as it's huge):

```
public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable
{    
//user stuff
private PlayerSprite player;                                //creates the player
private int score = 0;

//graphics
private int backgroundSpeed = 0;                            //sets speed the background scrolls at
private Bitmap bmp, bg, spaceships,
            a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6,
            a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12;                      //creates empty objects for all the sprites

//tech/threads
private SurfaceHolder holder;                               //creates the placement view
private Thread gameThread = null;
private boolean isPaused = false;   
static final long FPS = 30;
private boolean running = false;
private int speed = 0;


//sound
private SoundPool boom;
boolean loaded = false; 
private int kaboom;

//asteroid belts
private int numOfAsteroids = 12;
private Bitmap[] asteroids;
private ArrayList<Asteroid> activeAsteroids;
private ArrayList<Asteroid> deadAsteroids;


public GameView(Context context, int s) 
{
    super(context);

    speed = s;
    initialise();
    holder = getHolder();       

    gameThread = new Thread(this);

    holder.addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) 
        {
            boolean retry = true;
            running = false;

            while (retry) 
            {
                try 
                {
                    gameThread.join();
                    retry = false;
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) 
                {

                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            running = true;
            gameThread.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {
        }
    });             
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void initialise()
{
    //load graphics

    //initialises player
    player = new PlayerSprite(spaceships, this, 2, 5, 500, 800, speed); 

    //initialises blocks

    activeAsteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();
    deadAsteroids = new ArrayList<Asteroid>();

    //initialises sounds
    boom = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    boom.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) 
        {
            loaded = true;
        }
    });     
    kaboom = boom.load(this.getContext(), R.raw.boom, 1);
}   

public Bitmap getBmp() 
{
    return bmp;
}
public void setBmp(Bitmap bmp) 
{
    this.bmp = bmp;
}
public void setSpriteState(int val)
{
    player.setState(val);
}   
public int getScore()
{
    return score;
}

public void addAsteroid(Canvas c)
{
    activeAsteroids.add(new Asteroid(getAsteroid(), 1, 1, createAsteroidX(c), -200));
}

public Bitmap getAsteroid()
{       
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt(12);      
    return asteroids[i];        
}

public int createAsteroidX(Canvas c)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = r.nextInt((c.getWidth() - a1.getWidth()));

    return i;
}   

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
    backgroundSpeed += 10;
    if (backgroundSpeed > bg.getHeight() - getHeight())
    {
        backgroundSpeed = 0;
    }

    Rect src = new Rect(0, bg.getHeight() - getHeight() - backgroundSpeed, getWidth(), bg.getHeight() - backgroundSpeed);
    Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bg, src, dst, null);

    player.update(canvas);          

    if (activeAsteroids.size() == 0)                        //adds asteroids periodically
    {
        addAsteroid(canvas);
    }       

    for (Asteroid a : activeAsteroids)
    {           
        //a.move(canvas, 0, 10);                                //moves asteroids downward slowly
        a.move(canvas, 0, speed);

        if (player.collidesWith(a))                         //ends game
        {
            boom.play(kaboom, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1f);
            running = false;
            Paint pp = new Paint();
            pp.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
            pp.setTextSize(75);
            pp.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawText("You crashed.", getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, pp);
        }

        if (!a.getScored())                                 //adds score once when asteroid passes player
        {
            if ((a.getY() / 2) > (player.getY() / 2))
            {
                score++;
                a.setScored(true);
            }
        }           

        if (a.getY() > 1200)                                //removes asteroid from lists when passed bottom of screen
        {
            a.move(canvas, 10000, 10000);
            deadAsteroids.add(a);
            activeAsteroids.remove(a);
        }
    }

    for (Asteroid a : deadAsteroids)                        //removes asteroids in the dead list
    {
        deadAsteroids.remove(a);
    }

    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    p.setTextSize(100);
    canvas.drawText("" + score, (canvas.getWidth()/2) - 40, 1100, p);   
    canvas.drawText("" + activeAsteroids.size(), (canvas.getWidth()/2) - 40, 100, p);
    canvas.drawText("" + speed, (canvas.getWidth()/2) - 40, 600, p);
}

@Override
public void run() 
{
    long ticksPS = 1000 / FPS;
    long startTime;
    long sleepTime;
    while (running) {
        Canvas c = null;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            c = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            synchronized (getHolder()) {
                onDraw(c);
            }
        } finally {
            if (c != null) {
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        sleepTime = ticksPS - (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        try {
            if (sleepTime > 0)
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            else
                Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have all your game logic inside the View?

Comment: @donfuxx we've not learnt any other way in Android, what's more ideal?

Comment: I usually use game engines for graphics-intensive games. Currently I prefer libgdx. Anyhow, it is a bit harder to maintain the game logic, if it's all in one huge class like you did it.

Comment: @donfuxx this is for a university assignment so i'm a bit unsure how they see us using external libraries and engines. Thought i'd stay safe and keep it all mine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should be using something like Open GL ES to do this.

Anyway I would create a new activity for your GameOver Screen with a new view. You can then finish() the current activity when creating the new activity with the new View.

You can use intent to do this which makes switching between the two activities easy.

```
 void checkLives(Context mContext)
 {
    If(Lives == 0)
    {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, SaveScore.class);
            ((Activity)mContext).startActivity(intent);   
            finish();

    }
 }
```

Make Sure you finish() the activty or you could end up with multiple instances.

From the SaveScore activity you can then start a new game creating a new instance of the orignal activity.